# Select one time a column if same value in column more then one time

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current table structure

```
id       | product             | Price
---------|-------------------------------
01       | Motherboard         | 4000
02       | Processor           | 3000
03       | Motherboard         | 4100
04       | Motherboard         | 4150
05       | RAM                 | 1500
06       | Processor           | 2900
```

Here i want SQL query by which i can only select a value of field `product` one time like id 01,03,04 have same product & id 02,06 have same product so here only one row will be select from 01,03,04 & one row from 02,06 and also 05 will be selectd
please help. Table name is `productHistory`

Comment: You have to decide which one!

Answer (score 1):

QUERY will be `SELECT DISTINCT product FROM productHistory;`

Answer (score -1):

You can use either DISTINCT or GROUP BY for selecting unique values.

```
SELECT product
FROM ProductHistory
GROUP BY product;
```

Note: It is better to use **DISTINCT** rather than **GROUP BY** for selecting unique values.

Comment: This use of GROUP BY should be discouraged because it inevitably leads to chaos, confusion, errors, and the very breakdown of the fabric of human society.

Comment: I gave him an alternate solution to the DISTINCT version which was already given.